# Using templates to rewrite polymorphic class to one single class (compile time polymorphism)

Tags: class, c++11, templates, static-polymorphism

In my current code I use runtime polymorphism to create different subtypes of "light" from a LightBase class. The lighttypes however are already known at compile time (preprocessor picks the right variant). So I figured it is really not the right tool to do so as it is slow (vtable lookup for virtual getter functions) and could be already done at compile time. I just don't know how... could it be done with templates? I don't have too much experience in template programming so I don't know what is possible.

Essentially I want to instantiate a subclass of either type NormalLight or SpecialLight which have the same functions as LightBase but operate on a different set of constants:

```
class Color
{
    Color(std::string color_name) : color_name_(color_name) { }
    private:
        std::string color_name_;
}

class LightBase {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr& GetInstance() { return instance_; }

    protected:
        const resolution;
        std::array<Color, 0> = {  };
    // ..

    private:
        static std::unique_ptr<LightBase> instance_;
}

class NormalLight : public LightBase
{
    protected:
        const resolution = 9;
        std::array<Color, 3> { Color("blue"), Color("red"), Color("purple") };
    // ..
}

class SpecialLight : public LightBase
{
    protected:
        const resolution = 13;
        std::array<Color, 3> { Color("yellow"), Color("magenta"), Color("orange") };
    // ..
}

#if defined CONFIG_LIGHT_TYPE_NORMAL
std::unique_ptr<LightBase> LightBase::instance_ = std::unique_ptr<NormalLight>(new NormalLight());
#elif defined CONFIG_LIGHT_TYPE_SPECIAL
std::unique_ptr<LightBase> LightBase::instance_ = std::unique_ptr<SpecialLight>(new SpecialLight());
#endif
```

In a function I could conditionally check for a template parameter (I guess) but it's a class definition. Also, the thing should compile in C++11. Any ideas?

Comment: Normally static polymorphism in C++ means [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). But from what I understand all that the different classes hold are parameters and no functions, right?

Comment: I mean one option would be to rewrite the code and have a class `Light` which is templated with a template parameter `LightTrait`. The trait holds the different parameters only while the class `Light` holds the functions and accesses the different constants inside the `LightTrait`.

Comment: If that is really viable really depends on how your code is structured. As it is then `Light<T>` you could not push different kind of lights `T` into e.g. an `std::vector`. So please outline in more detail how you are using `LightBase`.

Comment: @2b-t: thanks for your hint! I had a look at CRTP and it looks like a beneficial pattern for my use case. Indeed, my Subclass only holds different data, the functionality is implemented in the base class. Can you outline in more detail how you would go about implementing LightTrait template parameter which holds data? The classes are allowed to have different signatures as there only ever exists exactly 1 light (hence I've implemented it now a kind-of singleton pattern). So no need to push it to a vector.